# How can I find all substrings, which are between two strings including a line-break using R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How would I find all substrings, which are between "##" and "\n“ or “{“?

For example, facing "## Test\n" or "## Test {", I would like to get back "Test".

I am not experienced in using Regex but started in trying

```
str_match("## Test\n", "## (.*?) \n")
```

using the stringr-package. But it seems as there is an issue with the line-break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
str_match("## Test\n", "##\s*([^\n{]*)[\n{]")
```

`##` matches ##

`\s*` matches any number of whitespace characters

`([^\n{]*)` will match and capture any number of characters that are not `\n` or `{`

`[\n{]` ends the pattern on either `\n` or `{`

Comment: I liked the answer but I would even go make it possessive for performance (see the + symbol after ]*)  ====>  '##\s*([^\n{]*+)[\n{]'

Comment: @ Tim Thank you very much for your solution. I had to add a slash to make it "\\s" but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an assertion and a negated class.
Putting a `\r` carriage return in the class will take care of line break issues.

`(?<=##)[^\r\n{]*`

What it matches is what you need.

Expanded

```
 (?<= \#\# )
 [^\r\n{]*
```

Also, if you anticipate `##` not separated by line breaks or {,
and is valid, use something like this

`(?<=##)(?:(?!##|[\r\n{])[\S\s])*`